# Eclipse graphiti tutorials

Tags: eclipse, graphiti

From where can I get the Eclipse Graphiti tutorials?

For more information on this software you can get here.

Also please let me know the knowledge of Eclipse plugin development and EMF is mandatory in better understanding of Graphiti?

[Eclipse Graphiti Link](http://www.eclipse.org/graphiti/)

Answer (score 3):

The tutorial is installed in the Eclipse help, together with the plugin. It's also accessible online in the global Eclipse online docs, it's accesible from [here](http://www.eclipse.org/graphiti/documentation/), clicking in "Graphiti online help" (I don't link it directly because the link changes over time). There are no other tutorials AFAIK.

And yes, you need to know the basics of Eclipse plugin development and EMF.